# Printing strings and arguments of functions in R

Tags: r

I've two questions about R. There are quite simple, but unfortunately I don't find something in the web.

1. Is it possible to write a function in R, `fun1<-function(place)` such that the argument "place" is the filename which I want to import in my case, i.e.

   ```
   fun1 <- function(place)
   data <- read.table(/home/place.csv, header=TRUE, sep=",")
   ```
2. Suppose the variable `c` is assigned to a number for example age of a person. Then I want to print out a string like this: `"hello my age is c"`. How do you do this in R?

Comment: See `?paste` `?cat` `?message`

Comment: The reason why I want to use a function is the following: I have to do some calculations / manipulations for a lot files (all .csv). First I have choosen `file.choose()`. I work with Emacs, but then I have to write everytime something like this: /home/dir1/dir2/filename.csv. So my idea was to use a function, where the argument is the filename. Let's assume I have to do this calculations for 200 files, I guess the function method is more efficient, isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You can use `sprintf`, `paste0`, etc for the first part.

   ```
   fun1 <- function(place) read.table(sprintf('/home/%s.csv', place), 
                                      header=TRUE, sep=",")

   fun2 <- function(place) read.table(paste0('/home/', place, '.csv'), 
                                      header=TRUE, sep=",") 
   # paste0 only works in recent versions of R

   fun3 <- function(place) read.table(paste('/home/', place, '.csv', sep=''),
                                      header=TRUE, sep=",")

   # Now call the functions
   fun1('test.csv')
   fun2('test.csv')
   fun3('test.csv')
   ```
2. `sapply` isn't needed since `paste` is vectorized.

   ```
   ages <- 10:20
   paste('Hello my name is', ages)
   ```

Comment: @ Erik Shilts: Thank you for your answer. However the first part does not work for me. Suppose my files are in `/home/dir1/dir2/`. Further, assume there's a file called test.csv (Full path is: /home/dir1/dir2/test.csv). If I write `fun1<-function(place) read.table(sprintf('/home/dir1/dir2/%s.csv',place),header=TRUE,spe=",")` then I get the error: object test.csv not found, when I call `fun1(test)`. What is wrong about my code? Additionally what's the `%s` for? Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: checkout `?sprintf` for help on that function. What it does is it allows you to specify holder places in a string. Try running something like `sprintf("Place1 [%s], Place2 [%s], Place3 [%s]", 'thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3')` to see how it works. Your error says that R is looking for an object called test.csv. Instead you should be passing the string 'test.csv' to the function.

Comment: @ Erik Shilts: Sorry if my comment was not clear or if I misunderstood your comment. What I did: I wrote a R-script, which contains the function fun1 described above. I loaded it with `source(name of R-script)`. Then I tried, fun1(test) and get the error mentioned in the previous comment. I also tried fun1(test.csv) with the same result.

Comment: See my example code above. You need to call the function surrounding test.csv in quotes: `fun1("test.csv")`

Comment: @ Mea culpa! Sorry, now everything works! Why do I have to put the function argument into ""? Otherwise R thinks place stands for a variable with a numerical value assigned? Or what causes the problem?

Comment: Without quotes it's looking for an object named `test.csv`. You could create such an object by `test.csv <- 'file_name.csv'` and then passing that to your function: `fun1(test.csv)`. This will attempt to read the table /dir1/dir2/file_name.csv.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve in the first part of your question. Can you explain that further?

For the second part, what about something like this:

```
> ages = c(40, 23, 13, 42, 53)
> sapply(ages, function(x) paste("Hello, my age is", x))
[1] "Hello, my age is 40" "Hello, my age is 23" "Hello, my age is 13" "Hello, my age is 42"
[5] "Hello, my age is 53"
```